# Convert string to an integer in c++

Tags: c++

I have a char string that contains a number between 0 and 60.  How can I convert this to an int?  The char contains a leading 0 if it is less than 10.

For example, I would like to convert char b[]="08"; to int n=8 or char b[]="41"; to int n=41;

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Convert+string+to+an+integer+in+c%2B%2B&oq=Convert+string+to+an+integer+in+c%2B%2B

Comment: int n = (b[0] - '0') * 10 + (b[1] - '0');

Comment: Seriously? No searchy? At least 15 duplicates were presented to you _as you typed your question_.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use boost, there is great function boost::lexical_cast

```
int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>("123");
```

c++11 also has function stoi (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

```
int x = std::stoi("123");
```

Comment: Obviously, you should prefer to use C++11

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string is null-terminated, you can use atoi() or sscanf to convert.

Example:

```
n = atoi(b);
```

or

```
sscanf( b, "%d", &n);
```

[edit]
Or you can do it the more pure C++ way:

```
#include <sstream> 

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << b;
    ss >> n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple C++ way of doing it :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int string_to_int (std::string const & str)
{
    std::istringstream iss { str };
    int value;

    iss >> value;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

C has the `atoi` method which you can use to convert a string to an integer:

```
int c = atoi("123"); //c == 123
```

documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Be warned that it won't throw any exceptions, and will cause undefined behaviour if the value passed in isn't an int or outside the range of a valid int

Comment: I don't know why this got a down-vote. it does exactly what the OP wants without the need to create a `std::string` or `stringstream`

Comment: I don't really know why people are not okay with using a C API in C++.   I don't think the poster cares what the API is as long as it's available in standard C++, unless they are explicitly asking, "I want to know how to do this in C++, not C".   I agree with raser.